# FailedPreconditionError: Table not initialized

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, nlp

I am trying to create an NLP neural-network using the following code:

imports:

```
import zipfile
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import TextVectorization,Embedding,Input,GlobalAveragePooling1D,Dense
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
```

Download and unzip dataset:

```
# Download data (same as from Kaggle)
!wget "https://storage.googleapis.com/ztm_tf_course/nlp_getting_started.zip"

# Unzip data
zip_ref = zipfile.ZipFile("nlp_getting_started.zip", "r")
zip_ref.extractall()
zip_ref.close()
```

Split data into train and test datasets:

```
    train_df = pd.read_csv("train.csv")
    
    train_sentences, val_sentences, train_labels, val_labels = train_test_split(train_df['text'], train_df['target'],train_size=.8)
    average_output_sequence_length = 15
```

Create the neural-network:

```
input = Input(shape=(1,),dtype='string')
x = TextVectorization(max_tokens=10000,
                      ngrams=5,
                      standardize='lower_and_strip_punctuation',
                      output_mode='int',
                      output_sequence_length = average_output_sequence_length)(input)
x = Embedding(input_dim=22,embeddings_initializer='uniform',output_dim=128, name= 'embeding_layer')(x)
x = GlobalAveragePooling1D()(x)
output = Dense(1,activation='sigmoid')(x)

model = tf.keras.Model(input,output)

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'] )

model.fit(x=train_sentences,y=train_labels,epochs=6,validation_data=(val_sentences,val_labels))
```

Unfortunately, when i run the code, i face with the following error:

```
Epoch 1/6
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FailedPreconditionError                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-52-991547d73612> in <module>()
     13 model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'] )
     14 
---> 15 model.fit(x=train_sentences,y=train_labels,epochs=6,validation_data=(val_sentences,val_labels))

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     57     ctx.ensure_initialized()
     58     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
---> 59                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     60   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:
     61     if name is not None:

FailedPreconditionError:  Table not initialized.
     [[node model_6/text_vectorization_7/string_lookup_7/None_Lookup/LookupTableFindV2
 (defined at /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/layers/preprocessing/index_lookup.py:669)
]] [Op:__inference_train_function_5066]

Errors may have originated from an input operation.
```

**UPDATE:**
I got it to work when i change the way that i use the functional code:

Create TextVectorization function:

```
text_vectorization_layer =  TextVectorization(max_tokens=10000,
                                              ngrams=5,
                                              standardize='lower_and_strip_punctuation',
                                              output_mode='int',
                                              output_sequence_length = average_output_sequence_length
                                              )
```

And then finally create the neural-network:

```
input = Input(shape=(1,),dtype='string')
x = text_vectorization_layer(input)
x = Embedding(input_dim=22,embeddings_initializer='uniform',output_dim=128, name= 'embeding_layer')(x)
x = GlobalAveragePooling1D()(x)
output = Dense(1,activation='sigmoid')(x)

model = tf.keras.Model(input,output)

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'] )

model.fit(x=train_sentences,y=train_labels,epochs=6,validation_data=(val_sentences,val_labels))
```

***QUESTION:***

But, i still do not understand why these change fix the issue ?

in other word, why the:

```
x = TextVectorization(input)
```

and the

```
x = TextVectorization(max_tokens=10000,
                      ngrams=5,
                      standardize='lower_and_strip_punctuation',
                      output_mode='int',
                      output_sequence_length = average_output_sequence_length)(input)
```

***are not equal ?***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `TextVectorization` layer is a preprocessing layer that needs to be instantiated before being called. Also as the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/TextVectorization) explain:

> The vocabulary for the layer must be either supplied on construction
> or learned via adapt().

Another important information can be found [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/preprocessing_layers#the_adapt_method):

> Crucially, these layers are non-trainable. Their state is not set during training; it must be set before training, either by initializing them from a precomputed constant, or by "adapting" them on data

Furthermore, it is important to note, that the `TextVectorization` layer uses an underlying `StringLookup` layer that also needs to be initialized beforehand. Otherwise, you will get the `FailedPreconditionError: Table not initialized` as you posted.

Comment: Do you mean a code like: `TextVectorization(max_tokens=10000,
                      ngrams=5,
                      standardize='lower_and_strip_punctuation',
                      output_mode='int',
                      output_sequence_length = average_output_sequence_length)(input)`

calls the `TextVectorization` before `instantiate it` ?

Comment: Yes, exactly, this line is not being instantiated..it is just calling the layer immediately.